# remove white space between fixed footer and main materialize

Tags: css, materialize

when i resize my index i show white space between main and footer, inside my main i have a carousel item.

Any suggestions to fix my space?

css to my footer:

```
    body {
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    main {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure your img inside the carousel is set to `height:100%`. Also, unrelated, but the text at  the bottom will not wrap unless there's a space.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "Sticky footer", that means it will always be at bottom.

> A sticky footer always stays on the bottom of the page regardless of how little content is on the page. However, this footer will be pushed down if there is a lot of content, so it is different from a fixed footer. Add the following code to your CSS file.

You can disable "sticky option" by removing css you posted, that means your footer will be displayed right behind that carousel. Also you can set body background color same as the footer to get rid of white rows.

You can also stretch your content.

This is not materialize issue, you just have to think about your layout.